# Graph Api Notification - Maximum length of subscription for user/group changes

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

What is  Maximum length of subscription for Graph Api Notification -about user/group resources changes?

Any option to set 'Never expiry' to Notification so no need to renew? If not possible why is it so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is Maximum length of subscription for Graph Api Notification
>   -about user/group resources changes?

The Maximum length of subscription of User,group, other directory entities is **4230 minutes (under 3 days)**. You can refer to this [document](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/4707/commits/ab958f19d31e4eebde07265e9ee94b76597390f7).

> Any option to set 'Never expiry' to Notification so no need to renew?
>   If not possible why is it so ?

**Note:** Existing applications and new applications should not exceed the supported value. In the future, any requests to create or renew a subscription beyond the maximum value will fail. Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0#maximum-length-of-subscription-per-resource-type).

If you still have concerns regarding this, you can send your feedback at the bottom of this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0#maximum-length-of-subscription-per-resource-type).

[image]

Comment: why change subscription is set to 4230 minutes?

Comment: @thiru This is the Maximum Expiration Time. This is by default design. If you have any concerns regarding this, you can send feedback at the bottom of this document. You will be replied by related Microsoft engineer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0#maximum-length-of-subscription-per-resource-type